# How to access photos/video folder of iOS and copy file to applicaton folder using Marmalade

Tags: ios, marmalade

I need to open iphone folder like photos/videos.
I need to show content of that folder to user and when user selects a file from that I need to copy that particular file from that folder to my application folder.

Let me know what APIs I need to use for that.
Also let me know whether this is feasible or not using `Marmalade`.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried looking at the s3eImagePicker example? under examples\s3e\s3eImagePicker